# Запись символа в новую строку в зависимости от положения в исходной строке

Tags: python, символы, строки

Дано: символьная строка следующего типа a10 b11 с0 !!9

Задача : записать новую строку, в которую будут записаны ASCII коды символов из строки

Исключение: если символ является частью выражения, стоящего после буквы (в нашем случае это 10, 11 и 0), то записывается сам символ. То есть на выход из

`a10 b11 с0 !!9`

мы должны получить

`01100001 10 00100000 01100010 11 00100000 01100011 0 00100000 00100001 00100001 00111001 00100000` без пробелов

Мое решение : посимвольный прогон через исходную строку, запись ASCII кода символа, если предыдущий элемент является пробелом. Если нынешний и следующий элемент - восклицательные знаки, то записываем ASCII код каждого символа до следующего пробела, включительно.

Как можно реализовать описанный мною алгоритм или улучшить его - идей нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю вам такой вариант. Он достаточно прост для понимания и последующей модификации:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
code_str = u' 1110 H001 d000 e1111 l10 o110 r010 w011 !!32' #  Исходная строка
code_list = code_str.split(' ') # Разделим исходную строку на блоки по пробелам

print code_list

# Функция превратит символ в бинарный код, нужного вам формата
def symbol_to_bin(smb):
    return bin(ord(smb))[2:].zfill(8)

# Функция конвертирует фрагмент строки в бинарные кода
def convert_code(code):
    if code:
        if len(code) > 1 and code[:2] == '!!': # Если первые 2 символа !!
            # Вернем все символы в виде бинарных кодов
            return [symbol_to_bin(x) for x in code]
        else:
            # Вернем первый символ в виде бинарного кода, а остальные как есть
            return [symbol_to_bin(code[0])] + [code[1:]]
    else:
        return []

# Получим массивы с результатом конвертации
res_blocks = [convert_code(x) + [symbol_to_bin(' ')] for x in code_list]

# Получим окончательную строку, склеив все массивы. Замените ' ' на '' чтоб получить склейку без пробелов.
res_str = ' '.join(sum(res_blocks, []))

print res_str
```

Comment: `if code[0] in lowercase: `

не вариант, так как символом, который кодируется может быть вообще любой символ из ASCII. То есть и заглавная буква, и прописная, и цифра, и знаки препинания с двоеточиями, кавычками и т.п.

Comment: @AlexSabelnikov, вы написали: _если символ является частью выражения, стоящего после буквы_. Как вы определяете символы после которых нужно что то менять, а после каких ненужно?

Comment: легче будет сказать после каких менять не нужно. Так, менять не нужно символы, стоящие после символа, перед которым пробел, и вплоть до нового пробела. Исключение - случай с двумя восклцательными знаками. То есть для набора ф10 !01 G00 1110 !!8 не будут меняться 10 01 00 110

Comment: @AlexSabelnikov обновил код в посте

Comment: попробуйте на входных данных
(пробел)1110 H001 d000 e1111 l10 o110 r010 w011 !!32
Индекс выходит за границы

Comment: @AlexSabelnikov обновил код в посте